# How do I get PushNotificationChannel.PushNotificationReceived event handler to intercept notifications?

Tags: c#, windows-8, notifications

The desired behavior is to intercept a raw notification in the app (without requiring either a background task or the user to give up one of their precious background task spots). Per the sample code at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ709907(v=win.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ709907%28v=win.10%29.aspx) I created an event handler to intercept raw notifications. In one app I created, using Azure Mobile Services to send notifications via WNS the event handler gets triggered and it works great.

But in a second app, its not working. Notifications seem to be fine. That is, when my web service gets WNS to send a Toast notification it shows up. Also, I can debug/trace raw notifications and they appear to be created just fine too. Is there some setting I'm missing?

I see the request and results via Fiddler, but maybe only because I'm running a MVC 4.0 Web API project locally??? Requests look like this:

```
{Channel URI:              https://bn1.notify.windows.com/?token=AgYAAACuGgtx...
TTL:                      -
Cache:                    no
Request for status:       no
Tag:                      
Priority:                 Normal
Token retry count:        0

really
}
```

Then I can trace this (all done through the WNSRecipe/NotificationsExtensions code that's part of the WAT samples). I get:

```
{Sent WNS notification: Received
Channel URI:              https://bn1.notify.windows.com/?token=AgYAAACuGgtx...
Notification status:      Received
Status code:              OK
Device connection status: NotApplicable
Error description:        
Debug Trace:              BN1WNS2011828
MessageId:                3FA318CE5C48E9CF
Timestamp:                3/8/2013 9:23:18 PM -07:00


- REQUEST ------------------------------------------------------------------
X-WNS-Type                    : wns/raw
Content-Type                  : application/octet-stream
Authorization                 : Bearer EgAaAQMAAAAEgAAACoAAx1d3DqT9jZxJdOFIUJ9...
Host                          : bn1.notify.windows.com
Content-Length                : 6

really

- RESPONSE -----------------------------------------------------------------
X-WNS-NOTIFICATIONSTATUS      : received
X-WNS-MSG-ID                  : 3FA318CE5C48E9CF
X-WNS-DEBUG-TRACE             : BN1WNS2011828
Content-Length                : 0
Date                          : Sat, 09 Mar 2013 04:23:11 GMT
}
```

And the result:

```
{Channel URI:              https://bn1.notify.windows.com/?token=AgYAAACuGgtx...
Notification status:      Received
Status code:              OK
Device connection status: NotApplicable
Error description:        
Debug Trace:              BN1WNS2011828
MessageId:                3FA318CE5C48E9CF
Timestamp:                3/8/2013 9:23:18 PM -07:00
}
```

So I assume the notifications are being sent.

An update: I've gone back and double-checked settings and added a test button in the app to POST my request. (So I know the app is active, no question). I added `RequestForStatus = true` to my notification request and am getting back "Device connection status: Connected" as well as new sets of log entries in the Event Viewer.

Comment: when you say debug/trace raw notifications appear to be **created ** fine, are you seeing them be delivered to the client (via say Fiddler) and just not acted on?

Comment: @ Jim O'Niel I've added more detail to this. I'm not exactly sure they're delivered to Windows8/my Win8 app. I just see them because I'm running a MVC app locally. Is there a way to get Fiddler to intercept notifications directly? Thanks, and BTW, your blog posts have been helpful.

Comment: on 2nd thought, skip fiddler.  In Event Viewer>Applications and Services Logs>Microsoft>Windows>Push Notifications-Platform is where (I believe) you should see what got to your machine.  I'm not completely versed in what shows up there, but might be worth a look to see if you're seeing an error or indication that the message was received (both in working and non-working case)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on looking at the Push Notifications-Platform logs. Notifications are being sent, although I'll need to spend more time in there to see what I can glean.

Comment: An app needs to be running to intercept any type of notification (including raw) via the the PushNotificationReceived event.  Was the second app up and running at the time the raw notification was sent/delivered?

Comment: @NathanKuchta Yes, the Win8 app is running at the time. With my WAMS-based app, an intercepted raw notification would work fine across three different machines, as long as the app is on the stack. I'm going to go back through all my settings and see if there's any mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After banging my head around all sorts of possible problems/solutions I finally found what was wrong. The culprit was in my event handler code. For whatever reason, code using the NewtonSoft JObject worked fine in my other test project, but was failing in a nasty and silent way in this project. I switched over to using ServiceStack.Text (which I'd been meaning to anyway since it is purportedly much faster...down the road I'll be piping a lot more data to and from the app besides terse raw notifications).

I went back to the most simple code first, doing nothing but:

```
private async void OnPushNotification(PushNotificationChannel sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NotificationType == PushNotificationType.Raw)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;

        String notificationContent = String.Empty;

        notificationContent = e.RawNotification.Content;
    }
}
```

This replaced the problem method which (FYI) looked like this:

```
private async void OnPushNotification(PushNotificationChannel sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    String notificationContent = String.Empty;

    switch (e.NotificationType)
    {
        case PushNotificationType.Badge:
        case PushNotificationType.Tile:
        case PushNotificationType.Toast:
            notificationContent = e.TileNotification.Content.GetXml();
            break;


        case PushNotificationType.Raw:
            notificationContent = e.RawNotification.Content;
            break;
    }

    e.Cancel = true;


    try
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(notificationContent);

        JToken jToken;

        jObject.TryGetValue("refresh", out jToken);

        bool refreshValue = jToken != null && Convert.ToBoolean(jToken.ToString());

        if (refreshValue)
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, RefreshTodoItems);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(err.Message);
    }
}
```

Finally, I ended up with this, which works just fine:

```
private async void OnPushNotification(PushNotificationChannel sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            if (e.NotificationType != PushNotificationType.Raw) return;
            e.Cancel = true;

            try
            {
                // Use ServiceStack.Text.WinRT to get this
                var jsonObj = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<JsonObject>(e.RawNotification.Content);

                // TODO: Do something with this value now that it works
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(err.Message);
            }
        });
}
```